# Black background on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, tweak

After I 'reset to defaults' on tweak, my desktop background looks like this
[image]

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You could try changing your wallpaper.

Comment: Yes. I changed. you can see the background in the edge of the screen

Comment: If you enable desktop icons, can you see files that are placed there?

Comment: No, I still can't

Comment: Needless to ask you did try rebooting or at least loging out then back in? Also check the "Adjustment" setting of the wallpaper in Gnome Tweaks. Other specifics on your setup? Do you have multiple screens?

Comment: @vanadium I tried rebooting several times and logging out then back in. There's nothing special in the setting of Gnome Tweaks. I use Ubuntu 20.04 so there's no "Adjustment" setting of the wallpaper. I have only 1 screen

Comment: What if you change the background to another wallpaper (and is that properly displayed?) then set it back?

Comment: @vanadium Yes. I tried all the ways but the background is still black

Comment: Create a new account and log in. Does it also happen under the new account?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling 'desktopfolder' resolved the issue in my case.

```
sudo apt-get purge desktopfolder
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
```